# Is "really" in the sense of "very", American English, or British English?

Tags: american-english, british-english

Or is it both? If it is American English, what would be the British English equivalent, or vice versa.

"I really like this dress" as in "I very much like this dress"

Comment: Speaking for the American side of things, either of those statements is perfectly normal, although the second sounds a bit more formal.

Comment: Ditto from a BrE speaker, the first is more natural.

Comment: *Really* meaning *indeed* (i.e. as an intensifier) as opposed to *in reality* (i.e. factually) is attested from the 16th century, before there was an American English to speak of. In any case, I usually refer to the amount of liking, rather than its intensity, i.e. *I like this dress very much* or *a great deal* or *a whole lot*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's not really (put intended) a difference in how often it occurs, in any case not significant enough to label either usage as American or British English.

Let's look at the usage of "I really like" and "I very much like"; that should eliminate most possibilities mentioned by @Laurel in the comments.

The [NGram graph for American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+really+like%2CI+very+much+like&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3):

[image]

and [the one for British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+really+like%2C+I+very+much+like&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3):

[image]

aren't that much different; you do see that 'really' gained a lot of traction in the last 60 years.

Comment: I don't think those graphs are accurate. For example, "the woman, **very much like** her sister,...", "it sounds **very much like** you want to go" and "what were they **really like**?" will be matched.

Comment: @Laurel In your examples, the word "I" is not included as it is in the displayed search strings. So your examples wouldn't be included.

Comment: @jejorda2 It wasn't when I posted that comment...

Comment: I would recommend, in order to answer the OPs direct question which is comparing the use of 'really' in AmE and BrE, selecting the corpus _for the same string_ 'really' in NGrams: [I really like:eng_us_2019,I really like:eng_gb_2019](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+really+like%3Aeng_us_2019%2C+I+really+like%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=17&smoothing=3)

Comment: With the more carefully selected ngrams, a good answer [but doubtless with  _(pun intended_) intended].